# Where to install JDK .tar.gz file on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04

Where is the recommended place to install the jdk .tar.gz file I just downloaded? I want it to be available for all users.

The installation guides that I have found told me to extract the jdk in many different places, such as `/opt`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local`. But the which one is the "right" choice? Why?

Comment: Have you tried the walkthrough steps listed on the Oracle website: [Installing the 64-Bit JDK 12 on Linux Platforms](http://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/install/installation-jdk-linux-platforms.html)? "Change the directory to the location where you want to install the JDK" which means you can use any of those paths (`/opt`, `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local`) since they are user-directories, not system-directories. Whichever directory you use, add it to `JAVA_HOME` variable as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/175547

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Into `/usr/lib/jvm/` folder, the reason is because the default installation path is that one when you use the `sudo apt install` command, which makes total sense to me.

Example:
**OpenJDK 11** is located at : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`
**OpenJDK 8** is located at  : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

For more information, you can read this article [here](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Answer (score 4):

First Download the Oracle JDK [Download Oracle JDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) or Open Jdk[Download Open JDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/),  then follow these commands :

1. First Unzip the tar file with this following command

   `tar zxvf <tar file name>`

Like : `tar zxvf jdk-11.0.2.jdk`

enter your password if asked

2. Now set the `JAVA_HOME` i.e system variables to the end of `/etc/profile` file
      first, open /etc/profile : `vi /etc/profile`
   and press I to insert and put this at the end

   `export JAVA_HOME=<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>`

   `export JAVA_HOME=/home/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

   `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

now press `ESC + SHIFT + :WQ` to save the changes

Answer (score 2):

For installation from the JDK tar.gz use the following command to unpack the tarball to the desired directory where you need to install java :

```
tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Then you can set the java home by editing the environment file and set java home like :

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

where the latter part is the directory in which you have installed java.Usually java will be installed in the `/usr/lib/` .Use an editor like nano or vim to edit the file and add the above key value to set java home.